# Contents of ArrayList gone

Tags: java, arraylist

So, this is my class:

```
public class SegmentMaker {

    public ArrayList<Segment> makeSegments(CustomNodes cn, Trip myTrip) {

        ArrayList<Segment> segments = new ArrayList<Segment>();
        ArrayList<Integer>segmentNodes = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        int count = 0; 

        for (int i=0; i < myTrip.getTripList().size(); i++){
            Log.d(TAG, "checking " + cn.getOsmID(myTrip.getTripItem(i)));

            if (i==0) {
                segmentNodes.add(myTrip.getTripItem(i));     
            }

            else if (i==myTrip.getTripList().size()-2) {
                segmentNodes.add(myTrip.getTripItem(i));     
            }

            else if (i==myTrip.getTripList().size()-1) {
                segmentNodes.add(myTrip.getTripItem(i)); 
                Segment segment = new Segment();
                segment.setId(count); 
                segment.setNodeIds(segmentNodes); 

                Log.d(TAG, "in SM segment " + segment.getId() + " nodes: " + segment.getNodeIds().toString());
                segmentNodes.clear(); 
                count++; 
                segments.add(segment);
                Log.d(TAG, "in SM segment " + segment.getId() + " nodes: " );
                for (int x=0; x<segment.getNodeIds().size(); x++) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "   " + segment.getNodeIds().get(x));
                }
                break; 
            }

            else if ((getAngle(myTrip.getTripItem(i), myTrip.getTripItem(i+1), myTrip.getTripItem(i+2),cn) < 25)  &&  
                    (getAngle(myTrip.getTripItem(i), myTrip.getTripItem(i+1), myTrip.getTripItem(i+2),cn) > -25))  
            {
                segmentNodes.add(myTrip.getTripItem(i));         
            }

            else {
                segmentNodes.add(myTrip.getTripItem(i)); 
                Segment segment = new Segment();
                segment.setId(count); 
                segment.setNodeIds(segmentNodes); 

                Log.d(ONE, "in SM segment " + segment.getId() + " nodes: " + segment.getNodeIds().toString());

                segments.add(segment);
                segmentNodes.clear(); 
                count++; 
            }
        }

        Log.d(TWO, " segments SM ende: " + segments.get(0).getNodeIds().size());
        return segments; 
    }

    public float getAngle(int firstItem, int secondItem, int thirdItem, CustomNodes cn){
        //do some stuff

        return angle;
    }
}
```

I'm sorry, it's much to read, what I'm trying to do is: a Segment has an ID and an ArrayList of NodeIDs. I collect all the NodeIDs until one doesnt pass the getAngle- check, then go to the next segment.

Where I Log.d with the ONE tag, all the NodeIDs are in the segment. Where I Log.d with the TWO tag, the ArrayList of NodeIDs is empty. When I return the segments- ArrayList, the segments in it are there (havin an ID), but the NodeID- ArrayLists of all the segments are empty. Where am I losing the content? I'm going crazy over this.

Comment: I removed BOTH segmentNodes.clear(), now it isnt working as I expected but at least theres some content in those ArrayLists. It's totally new to me that this also clears the ArrayLists that I have already "stored away". Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue stems from a misunderstanding of how Java handles Objects and references.

```
segmentNodes.add(myTrip.getTripItem(i)); 
Segment segment = new Segment();
segment.setId(count); 
segment.setNodeIds(segmentNodes); 

Log.d(TAG, "in SM segment " + segment.getId() + " nodes: " 
    + segment.getNodeIds().toString());
segmentNodes.clear(); 
count++; 
segments.add(segment);
```

Let's take a look at what Java is going to your objects as you "store" them.  In the first chunk, you added a "trip" to `segmentNodes`.  Then you added a **reference** to `segmentNodes` to the newly created Segment object.  Because you added a reference, all changes made to `segmentNodes` will also be seen within the `Segment`'s reference of `segmentNodes`.

Then you printed some data out, but you aren't altering anything so nothing should change.

Then, you call `segmentNodes.clear()`.  This cleared out all the data in `segmentNodes`, but since you gave a reference of `segmentNodes` to the `segment` instance, it lost all the integers, too.  Now, if you want the `segment` object to have its own **copy** of the `segmentNodes` list so that changes to the `segmentNodes` list does not affect the list in the Segment instance.

To do that, manually create a copy:

```
ArrayList<Integer> segCopy = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for(Integer i : segmentNodes){
    segCopy.add(i);
}
segment.setNodeIds(segCopy);
segmentNodes.clear();
```

Java does not pass copies of Objects, it passes a copy of the reference.  You may find this [Stackoverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference) about this topic helpful.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation. Its kinda strange that in over a year of java programming i've never come across this.